# serial in sys.version_info of python

Tags: python, sys

The sys.version_info output is ('major', 'minor', 'micro', 'releaselevel', 'serial'). I find that most of the explanations of this function outputs serial=0. I really don't understand what is this 'serial'? What does it mean? Why is it always 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.serial` part of the named tuple `sys.version_info` is always `0` for final releases, and when you download and install any version of Python from `python.org`, you're downloading final releases.

However, alphas, betas and candidates can have different serials.

See also the documentation on [API and ABI versioning on python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/apiabiversion.html#apiabiversion).

The specific example given there:

> PY_RELEASE_SERIAL 
> The 2 in 3.4.1a2. Zero for final releases.

This makes sense because there can be a series of alpha releases, and the serial number tells you which alpha you're looking at. Similarly, there can be multiple betas and even multiple release candidates. But there's always only a single final release, which will have number `0`.

Any official releases after that would get a new version number, and they would go through the same process until they achieve a new final release, again with serial `0`.